# Saltstack: How to install a new zypper RPM Repo?

Tags: saltstack, zypper

How to add a new rpm package repo via saltstack?

I checked the docs, and only see method to list, modify or delete repos:

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.zypper.html

I would like to do this:

```
root@server# zypper ar https://myserver/my-funny-repo-url.repo
```

sls file:

```
zypper_repo:
  pkgrepo.managed:
    - mirrorlist: https://myserver/my-funny-repo-url.repo
    - failhard: True
```

Error:

> CommandExecutionError: Zypper command failure: Repository
>   'zypper_repo' is invalid.
>
> [zypper_repo|https://myserver/my-funny-repo-url.repo]
>
> Valid
>   metadata not found at specified URL Please check if the URIs defined
>   for this repository are pointing to a valid repository. Skipping
>   repository 'zypper_repo' because of the above error.
>   Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [documentation you linked](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.zypper.html#salt.modules.zypper.mod_repo):

> salt.modules.zypper.**mod_repo**
>   Modify one or more values for a repo. **If the repo does not exist, it will be created**, so long as the following values are specified:

Comment: And how to use this module in a sls-file?